# R igraph package - changing arrow head shape

Tags: r, igraph, shapes

I am fairly new to this whole R coding malarky, but needed to take the plunge for my social network analysis and visualisation. However I encountered an issue with the igraph package that I am using in R. Although I am able to chnage the line width, type, vertex colour, shape etc etc I have been unable to change the arrow head shape. I spent a fair amount of time searching online, but to no avail. The only website I found that pertains directly to my situation is:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph/+bug/1026648

Therefore I was wondering if anyone here would know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to change it currently.

More precisely, because igraph is open source, you can just take the source code and code the different shapes if you are really committed to do this and have the time.

Alternatively, you can export your network in some format (probably GraphML or GML are the best options), and then use some other software to draw it. E.g. [Gephi](http://gephi.org) is quite popular nowadays, it probably supports various arrow shapes.